# How to add hyperlink on banner back to homepage

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, banner

I have a wordpress blog and I wanted to add a link to my banner that when clicked it sends you back to the homepage.  I know wordpress has this feature with the 'title' setting but I had to remove that field in order for my banner to appear on its own.

Any help on how to hyperlink the banner? Thanks!
Link to my [Blog](http://tradingliberation.com)

Comment: some code can be helpful to answer

Answer (score 0):

add a height to the anchor text on your siteName

```
#header .siteName a {
  margin-top: 25px;
  display: block;
  height: 118px;
}
```

That's line 166 of your http://tradingliberation.com/wp-content/themes/mxs2/style.css file.

Answer (score 0):

I would remove margin-top on global nav (line 190) in style.css. And then add height:118px; to #header .siteName a on line 167.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, I don't really understand what you guys mean (just started using coding when I created this blog little less than 2 months ago).

How exactly would adding height to #header .sitename make the banner a hyperlink to the homepage?